# How to stop UICollectionViewCell property expend-collapsed

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, keyboard, uicollectionview, uitextfield

```
 UICollectionViewCell get collapsed while Keyboard Rise.
```

In my TableViewCell I am having UICollectionView and In UICollectionViewCell I am having UITexttFields. Now as user click on UITextField Keyboard rise-UP and with this UICollectionViewCell collapsed.  So My question is how to stop UICollectionViewCell property expend-collapsed.

First without Keyboard :-

[image]

Second with Keyboard :-

[image]

Third with Keyboard :-

[image]

Comment: your issue is when keyboard appears this hides the back view ?

Comment: Basically when Keyboard appears CollectionViewCell collapsed. because its UICollectionView property to let selected cell to visible place.